# Eclipse fails to compile generic code, but mvn compile works

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, guava

In Eclipse Kepler 4.2 with jdk 1.7 I get following error in Eclipse:

> `The method or(capture#2-of ?) in the type Optional<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)`

whereas it compiles successfully when running `mvn compile`.

The **class** looks following:

```
package testit;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public class Test {

    private static final Object NO_VALUE = new Object();

    public void method(Map<String, ?> map) {
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Optional.fromNullable(entry.getValue()).or(NO_VALUE);
//                                                  ^^ error here
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>testit</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          <version>13.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The similar code runs on production for a long while without errors (in this area). It is compiling in Maven, Jenkins, Intelij but not in Eclipse. Question is why it does not compile in Eclipse ?

Comment: +1 Confirmed here as well. Well done for supplying good example code in your question. Interestingly, the embedded Maven in Eclipse can also build it.

Comment: Could you check whether the compiler's compliance settings in Eclipse are are for Java 7?

Comment: @robermann In my case, they are. Eclipse m2e configures compiler compliance settings based on the POM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a deep analysis by the Eclipse Team (btw great thanks!) their answer on this problem is following

Quoted after Stephan Herrmann from [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432603):

> This line doesn't apply for the following reason:
>
> Type inference starts by resolving this expression:
>
> `Optional.fromNullable(entry.getValue())`
>
> In this expression all elements can be typed as stated above:
>
> entry :            Entry   entry.getValue:
>   `capture#2-of ?   fromNullable(..) : (capture#2-of ?) ->`
>   `Optional<capture#2-of ?>`
>
> In short: T is inferred to be "`capture#2-of ?`". Inference succeeds.
>
> Only after all these have been decided, does resolution proceed to
>   inspect the .or(..) method call. No reason to fill in un-inferred
>   inference variables with "Object".
>
> With a receiver of type Optional, we have these three
>   overloads of "or":
>
> Optional or(Optional)
>   `capture#2-of ? or(Supplier<? extends capture#2-of ?> supplier)`
>   `capture#2-of ? or(capture#2-of ? defaultValue)`
>
> None of these methods is applicable for an argument of type Object.
>   ecj arbitrarily picks the first method for error reporting:
>
> "The method or(Optional) in the type
>   Optional is not applicable for the arguments (Object)"
>
> The difference between ecj and javac is most certainly covered by the
>   mentioned javac bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8016207
>
> As mentioned in that bug, a future update of the JLS may possibly
>   adopt parts of the current javac behavior. Until such a spec update is
>   released, the only reliable point of reference for ecj is the JLS. In
>   this specification I see no reason for changing the behavior of ecj in
>   this regard.
>
> BTW, the canonical fix (no cast needed) is:
>
> `Optional.<Object>fromNullable(entry.getValue()).or(NO_VALUE);`

For now that would be the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state a question so I assume the question: "Who is right, and how to make the code work?"

I'd say Eclipse is right.

The result of `fromNullable` has Type parameter `?`, i.e. there exists a type `T` but we don't know it.

The `Optional` returned by `or` must have the same type parameter as the `Optional` it is called on, which also means it takes the same unknown type `T` as a parameter. But `Object` might or might not be compatible to that type, so it is correct to fail.

In order to fix it, I think the following change should work:

```
Optional.fromNullable((Object)entry.getValue()).or(NO_VALUE);
```

The cast binds the otherwise unknown type parameter to `Object` which obviously is compatible to `Object` in the call to `or`.

Comment: Given the contents of your answer, specifically "*so it is correct to fail*", do you actually think Eclipse is right, not Maven?

Comment: Oops yes. Fixed it. Thanx for spotting it.

Comment: It raises the question of what is defined as "right". Maven just uses the local `javac`, which is perhaps right by default. Eclipse has its own incremental compiler, which I'd probably question before I'd question Oracle's implementation. I wonder if the language spec has a view on this.

Comment: @JensSchauder thanks for the remark about missing question which I forgot to emphasize. The problem is following that the code runs on production for a long and it is building on Jenkins, maven, intelij. I joined the project and checkout the code with eclipse where I encountered an Error. Adding the cast hides the problem. I would prefer to find some other resolution. In fact my intelij equipped colleagues are only waiting to hear that eclipse does not get along with the code while intelij does ;)

Comment: @kubagruszka in that case: Why the heck are you still using Eclipse when Intellij seems to be available?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse compiler is **not the standard javac**. It uses the [ECJ Compiler](http://blog.deepakazad.com/2010/05/ecj-eclipse-java-compiler.html) This is definitely a bug in the Eclipse Compiler, as maven uses the standard javac to compile that's why it's working.

Comment: Rumors say even javac sometimes contains bugs.

Comment: @JensSchauder sure, it might. But I'd question the Eclipse Compiler first.

Comment: I agree in the general case, but I can't see how it makes sense to compile this.

Comment: @JensSchauder a small search revealed this: 15.12.2.8 *Any remaining type variables that have not yet been inferred are then inferred to have type Object*

Comment: I've submitted bug in [Eclipse bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432603)

Comment: @Eugene So you are saying the rest of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8 does not apply? I'd be interested in why, because I don't even understand it.

Comment: @JensSchauder I wish I could tell you why, but I can't. I gave that reference there as it is the only one that I found to bring *some* light into why it is working with javac. I might be, of course, wrong here.